# What is the best way to split a list at first occurrence of an item in Scala?

Tags: scala

What is the best way of splitting a `List` at the first occurrence of an element that meets a specific condition? If no element in the list satisfies the condition, the original list should be returned.

I have a class defined as follows:

`class Entry(val time: Long, val info: String, val result: Boolean)`

I then have a list of these entry objects: `List[Entry]`. 
What is the best way of splitting the list at the first occurrence of an element that has `result=true`? So lets say you have a list: 
`List(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7)` where `e4` and `e6` have `result=true` then the returned result should be two lists as follows: 
`(List(e1,e2,e3), List(e4,e5,e6,e7))`. Or if none of the elements have `result=true` then the list `(List(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7), List())` should be returned.

I have already tried using `.indexOf` and `.splitAt` but that didn't seem to work:

```scala
val list = List(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7)
val (beforeSuccess, afterSuccess) = list.splitAt(list.indexOf(_.result == true))
```

Comment: You want two different result types _(`(List[Entry], List[Entry])` or `List[Entry]`)_, that is not possible in **Scala**.  You would need to use an **Either** or say that if none of the elements satisfy the condition the first component of the tuple should be empty, if this is what you want Tims answer should work.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes sorry I was ambiguous about that. Will edit it now.

Comment: This really isn't the same question as the one marked as a duplicate, though it would not surprise me if this particular question had been asked before.

Comment: @Tim the somewhat counter-intuitive meta rule is:[*"If a copy-paste answer works for a new question, then it is a duplicate irrespective how different the questions are."*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315296/2707792). The answer to the linked duplicate contains the sentence *"`span` [...] returns the longest prefix of the list whose elements all satisfy the given predicate, and the rest of the list."*. This quote answers the present question completely. Three paragraph long introduction about "Entries" and "time/info/results" is random noise that doesn't add anything to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `span` method:

```
list.span(_.result == false)
```

This is equivalent to `takeWhile/dropWhile` but possibly faster.